# Visual Studio 2005 C++ runtime new exception

Tags: visual-c++, debugging, release, new-operator

I have a VS 2005 C++ project with both Debug and Release builds.  I've attempted the following 4 things:

1. Build a Debug executable through Visual Studio, and run it through Visual Studio.
2. Run the executable built in (1) externally via command line (Cygwin) after `cd`'ing to `vstudio/debug`.
3. Build a Release executable through Visual Studio, and run it through Visual Studio.
4. Run the executable built in (3) externally via command line (Cygwin) after `cd`'ing to `vstudio/release`.

The first 3 all succeed: the program runs to completion.

The fourth, however, crashes at runtime.  Debugging shows that the culprit is the call to `malloc()` inside the operator `new()`.  The relevant context looks something like this:

```
template<typename T> class Foo {
    ...
    static void bar() {
        ...
        T* ptr = new T();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

If anyone can think of any problem which would lead to the 3-out-of-4 symptoms I describe, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a corrupt heap. This can be caused by a pointer writing outside the allocated memory.

A possible reason why this does not happen in debug mode is that you only overwrite debug information on the heap (which is not present in release mode).

I don't know you environment but you should probably get a tool like BoundsChecker to find the bug.

Comment: Quite likely. The OS uses a different heap when programs run under the debugger. Check with AppVerifier.

Comment: The heap corruption hypothesis seems likely.

Before I look into some of these other tools, though, do you have a hypothesis for why it would work for (3) but not (4)?

Comment: for (3) - when you say 'run' from VS do you mean launching or debugging?

Comment: In that case it doesn't surprise me too much. I encountered similar bugs that would not show up while debugging (the debugger affects the debugged app). One of those was caused by the compiler itself and fixed by a 'rebuild all'. It probably won't help in your case but I'd give it a try.

Comment: Indeed, it is a heap corruption problem.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that cygwin has replacement DLL's for some of the Windows DLL's that your program was built to use.

A good way to test this would be to try running under the Windows command shell (cmd.exe) and see if you get the same error.

Comment: I attempted running under Windows command shell.  I got the same error, although strangely, it was not at the exact same spot as when I launched with cygwin.  It was the same templatized call `Foo<T>::bar()`, although with a different `T`.

Comment: In that case, I think I'm with Chris.